# Convert an array to an "array of associative arrays" in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to do another silly thing in jQuery...

I have a bunch of strings in an array:

`[ var1 , var2 , var3 , var4 , var5 , var6 , var7 , ...]`

And I want the array to become an "array of associative arrays", with the same index every time... (don't ask me why xD):

`[ { 'variable' : var1 } , { 'variable' : var2 } , { 'variable' : var3 } , ... ]`

The index 'variable' is the same every time.

How does one do this? My attempt (below) isn't working...

```js
var stringarray = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'];
var assarray = {};

$.each(stringarray, function(index, value) {

  assarray[index] = {
    'variable': value
  };

});
document.write(JSON.stringify(assarray))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What isn’t working? It seems to work fine. Why did you use an object (`{}`) instead of an array (`[]`) for `assarray`? You can do the same thing without jQuery: `stringarray.map(function(a){return {"variable": a};})`.

Comment: Non-jQuery ES6: `var out = arr.map(el => ({ variable: el }))`...

Comment: But, yeah, `var assarray= {}` needs to be `var assarray= []` as answered below.

Comment: Just change `assarray={}` to `assarray=[]` to get your wish

Comment: Yeah, that was my mistake. There were so many things going wrong that I got kindof desperate. I had `assarray=[];` first but probably had something else mixed up at that time... Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically because assarray is not an array. It needs to be:

```
var assarray = [];
```

Also you could do:

```
var assarray = $.map(stringarray, function(val){ return {variable:val};});
```

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get it working. Turns out however that the array I was trying to parse has over 100.000 entries which just gave me a BSOD, LOL! Guess I'll have to find another solution... :-P

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, definitely use `map`. But I'd just use use the built-in since ES5:

```
var assarray = stringarray.map(function(element){ 
   return { variable: element };
});
```

Check out the [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Should work on every browser since IE9.

Comment: Well he already has jQuery so unless he already knows IE8 and lower are out of the picture then using jQuery is less work.

Comment: Not necessarily disagreeing with you here, but I feel the non-jquery version is generally more elegant and should be used whereever you can :)